# How do you make a rigid body eventually converge to a fixed position?

Tags: game-physics, physics, rigid-bodies, physics-engine

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zz7XJ6bK_YQ

What is the best way to think about writing a program for a free-falling, bouncing 2D rigid body like the one in this video that eventually converges (or appears to do so) to a fixed position? If possible, I would be glad to hear your mathematical and physical views, as well as any applications in the case of 3D.

I can reproduce the free fall and bounce of a rigid body, but I don't know how to think about the final stop at a fixed position.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you're using your simulation for and how accurate do you want your results to be. For example if you're using it as a visual tool / game development context, you can implement a naive approach by using a threshold for the object's speed, for example `Vt+1-Vt<0.01`. Once the object attains that speed minimum you can just consider it as stationary.